# Android - как правильно использовать цикл for-next в данной ситуации?

Tags: android, массивы, textview, ratingbar

Здравствуйте! У меня есть огромное количество TextView и RatingBar (75 штук), которые определены как t1...t75 (TextView) и r1...r75(RatingBar). При определённом событии вызывается метод checkData(), в котором для каждого TextView и RatingBar есть инструкция:
    `if (String.valueOf(SavedDataManager.getSetting("t1_data", "")).equals("non_passed")) t1.setTextColor(Color.rgb(80, 80, 80));
        if (String.valueOf(SavedDataManager.getSetting("r1_data", "")).equals("non_passed")) r1.setEnabled(false);`

Как вы видите, выполнять тоже самое 75 раз для каждого элемента - займёт очень много места в коде, поэтому я хотел добавить все эти элементы в массив (для TextView массив один, а для RatingBar - другой), а потом просто проверять значения циклом for-next. Но вот напасть - я вообще не умею работать с массивами, и тем более использовать их в циклах. Пожалуйста, помогите мне придумать что-нибудь! Код очень приветствуется.

---

P.S. ***На плюсы не скуплюсь!***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArrayList<TextView> tvs=new ArrayList<TextView>();
//blah-blah 1
tvs.add(myTextView);
//blah-blah 2

for(TextView tv:tvs) {
   if(...) {
     //blah-blah 3
     tv.setText("Blah-blah 4");
     //blah-blah 4
   }
   //blah-blah 5
}
```

**Update**

Где-то читал что программирование это способ написать 1 раз в цикле вместо того, чтобы повторять 75 раз одно и то же...

Comment: Ну хоть какой-то ответ, где меня не посылают в гугл)

Comment: У меня сын 11 лет и то сейчас знает как работать в цикле, удивляюсь как вы не умеете обращаться с циклами - это же половина программирования (вторая половина `if-then-else`)

Comment: Ну, с if-then-else я более-менее норм